# Add Custom filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type

I have create custom post type and add one meta box for ordering. I have add ordering meta-box too. But now i want to add a filter in post type for show up / show out. when admin click on show up then all the post will showing order wise of the meta box that admin you in meta box. It this possible. Also please see the images so i'll clear for you.

[image]

[image]

Search working from the product ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Well all the records in the admin section in WP are rendered using Wp_List_Table class, more info you can find [here](http://wpengineer.com/2426/).